# Need a technique to rectify high voltage high frequency

Tags: high-frequency

I recently made a high frequency transformer which I will be using to drive a large spark gap tesla coil. I machined the bobbin at work from nylon and bought the 60x55x15 cores on Mouser to form a 120x55x15 core which I will expect to handle at least 1kw input and has already been tested to over 4kw input and is holding up very well with no signs of failing. I have also made taps on the primary coil (5,10,15turns) to vary output voltage and power respectively. Now I need an efficient technique to rectify this transformer.

I understand I need avalanche rated diodes. My question is, are ultra fast diodes such as a recovery time of <75ns for example automatically rated as avalanche. I do not fully understand what makes a diode avalanche so I'm struggling to find some from RS Components although I do know they are designed to break down to handle reverse voltages in a controlled fashion.

Switching frequency is 45khz on a full bridge, output voltage on the primary tap of 15turns is roughly 20kv on the secondary

Thanks

Comment: expected current?

Comment: A maximum of 250ma

Comment: I was intending to buy several single diodes from RS Components UK and making a series string, then they will be housed in the oil with the transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Or use 40 per string for margin.  1N4007  8pF each
But verify L and SRF freq.
[image]

Insert diode PCB in oil.

**BEWARE** that forward capacitance increases with current and Ri decreases and  trr recovery time increases.  So if your average current is 250mA yet peak current 10x this you will have a trr problem so use faster diodes such as RS1MWF ( Diodes inc.) SMD.

[image]

or Buy from [here](http://www.edal.com/miniature.html)

Then you need these.

[image]

Comment: I was intending to buy several single diodes from RS Components UK and making a series string, then they will be housed in the oil with the transformer. As above thanks

Comment: The Oil will add many pF unless you coat the solder joints & leads in Silicone

Comment: I see, so can I just leave the transformer in oil and the series diode string in air? I see people using UF4007 but I was told to use avalanche rated diodes

Comment: 8pF is not bad for each in series. You're going to use > 80 diodes?

Comment: Are all ultrafast diodes avalanche rated?

Comment: 1N4007 have perhaps 5-30\$ \mu\$s trr, not at all suitable for 45kHz. They're okay at 60Hz or 400Hz.

Comment: It depends on allowed forward and reverse current, if both are limited to 250mA then Cd @ 0V=25pF  C @ 1kV=8pF  I would expect 1~2us trr  yet RS1MWF  SMD parts are at 0.5Af,1Ar are 250ns typ

Comment: I wonder who said -1

Comment: Thank you for the help Tony, so could I use any generic ultra fast rectifying diode such as uf4007? I was suggested this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/Vishay+Semiconductor+Diodes+Division/SF5408-TR/SF5408CT-ND/3104403              It says avalanche rated but when for instance I select on RS Components out of the approximate 11000 diodes under their rectifying and schottky diodes only about 30 are listed as avalanche, surely I'm missing something, thanks.

Comment: That's good enough.  but pricey  $75/100 again put on board in oil. and avoid all dust.

Comment: That is why I'm trying to find a cheap alternative I will need many of them, even 40 or so for half wave to be on the safe side.

Comment: How will you current limit them is the main issue.  I think 1N4007's cheap and will work to 250mA peak  Slow ramp up?

Comment: $11.11 /100 pc/

Comment: The coil must be air core not oil core for high SRF. But the diodes must be oil immersed due to small size.  You can detect partial discharge with an AM or SW radio like lightning before corona.

Comment: Output current on the secondary high voltage side can be limited using a variable air gap in the transformer core, 1amp diodes will prove effective, but the transformer is running at 45khz,  spark gap tesla coils require HVDC or mains frequency transformers, at high frequency capacitor bank charging becomes problematic as the spark gap cannot fire in the order of kilohertz, that's why I need to rectify it.

Comment: maybe add a thermistor for OTP shutdown before it blows up to ferrite